# Image not showing when img part is brought via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a path of an image from mysql via php to this ajax.

I should be able to view the image, but the image is not showing?

"CurrentVal" is showing the correct path. Means the php is successfully passing the data on to the ajax. (shows "img/logo.jpg")

```
var imageX;
var groupX;     

$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'php/myphp.php',
    dataType:'json',
    async: 'false',
    success: function(response){
    imageX   =   response[0].imgPath,
    groupX   =   response[0].titleVal;
    var s = document.getElementById("CurrentVal");
    s.value = imageX;

    var image = { **//object**
        'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
        'front': { 'url':'img/background.jpg', 'img':null }
    };

var canvas = {'temp':null, 'draw':null};
var mouseDown = false;
}
});
```

But if I replace  imageX

```
'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
```

with the path

```
'back': { 'url':'img/logo.jpg', 'img':null },
```

then everything works.

But I want to be able to make this work using the image path sent via php-mysql. Can someone help?

Comment: You might want to `console.log(imageX);` to check what the value is.

Comment: Thanks Graham. It's undefined.  When I do this (s.value = imageX;) it shows the correct value.  But when I do this (s.value = console.log(imageX);) it's undefined.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood what `console.log` does. Basically it outputs the variable to a console where you can debug it. Can you confirm that some of your code has been removed? I can't see where the variable `image` is used after you declare it... same for `canvas` & `mouseDown`

Comment: Yes... I've removed the bottom half of my code as the issue is in this particular part.

Comment: Ok. Above the line `var image = { **//object**` can you insert `alert(imageX);` and verify that the popup dialog displays the correct value?

Comment: Yes... the popup shows the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your comment `**//object**` should read:

```
var image = { /* object */
    'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
    'front': { 'url':'img/background.jpg', 'img':null }
};
```

Also change to comma on the end of `imageX   =   response[0].imgPath,` to a semicolon.

I can't believe it took me that long haha

Comment: Did not work. I even removed the comment, but still doesn't work.

Comment: The popup doesn't show when I tried `alert(image);`  above 
`var canvas = {'temp':null, 'draw':null};`

Comment: You're going to have to post the rest of your JavaScript, I can't see anything else wrong with the code you've posted. p.s. what browser/os are you using? Just so I can give you instructions on opening the console.

Comment: I use FF and chrome. Win7.  Thanks Graham.

Comment: Can you try changing that comma? To open the console in Chrome hold down the following keys: `Ctrl + Shift + J`
Then you'll be able to see any error and you'll be able to use `console.log();`

Comment: The console says ReferenceError: Components is not defined

Comment: Ok, first what **exactly** do you expect the value of `imageX` to be? The reason being your code above is `'url':imageX` but your actual code is `'url': 'img/' + imageX + '.jpg'`. Under where you declare image add `console.log(image.back.url);`... is this output correct? If so, in your `loadImages` function add `console.log(image[k].url);` under `image[k].img.src = image[k].url;`... is this output correct?

Comment: The image path is correct. should be `img/' + imageX + '.jpg` (imageX = logo)  |  `console.log(image.back.url);` - is correect.  |  `console.log(image[k].url);` nothing shows

Comment: Sorry,  console.log(image[k].url); shows img/undefined.jpg  and img/tickt.jpg

Comment: Your javascript works fine for me, can you post the address of your php file? You can delete your comment after we get it working.

Comment: Sorry I was after the url address of the file, so that I could run a live query.

Comment: I'm sorry Graham. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to do that.Are you able to use the php I posted?

Comment: wish I had got this sorted and solved with your help. I really appreciate your help/time.